# A crystal's effective series resistance effect on circuit operation

Tags: crystal

I am trying to replace our current through hole crystals with a surface mount version. I have found a SM equivalent however the only difference is the max ESR rating on the through hole is 25 ohm whereas the SM is 40 ohms. Will this have a sluggish effect on the circuit? Or can the SM version be implemented?

Comment: You should provide full datasheets for both crystals if you want a better answer.

Comment: No target circuit equals no real help.

Comment: Here are the two components. Data sheets are located in the link:
http://uk.farnell.com/ael-crystals/x19m660800l307/crystal-19-660800mhz/dp/9509402?ost=9509402&searchView=table&iscrfnonsku=false&ddkey=http%3Aen-GB%2FElement14_United_Kingdom%2Fsearch

http://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/IQD-Frequency-Products/LFXTAL003832Bulk/?qs=%2fha2pyFadujp3rxyGfnqiasLGBELrRbLsgzkwu0vP%252bM%252bYIIO23xW5NT8ViJTFRKs

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your driver circuit, how much of negative resistance it provides. It is not clear in first place that the 25-Ohm crystal was selected optimally. Usually there is enough room to accommodate a range of xtals, the 25 or 40 is not much of a difference.

The other thing to care about is the circuit drive strength relative to max dissipation power in xtal. Xtals should not be over-driven, and smaller SMD  packages usually have much-much smaller limit. If your driver is NOT a 1.2 V or 1.8 V circuit with limited output impedance, the design might be in trouble.